# Location services causing Null Pointer exception at times when setting Geocoder params

Tags: android, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

At times, I get `Null Pointer Exception` at line -

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
```

When I point my cursor to Locale.getDefault(), it says-

> Since the user's locale changes dynamically, avoid caching this value.
>   Instead, use this method to look it up for each use. It throws Null
>   Pointer Exception if the Locale is null.

Getting the location service of the user is the background task in my application that is running asynchronously `onCreate()` within activity.

**Error Log-**

```
03-31 15:04:11.613: W/System.err(5213): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 15:04:11.613: W/System.err(5213):     at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
03-31 15:04:11.614: W/System.err(5213):     at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
03-31 15:04:11.614: W/System.err(5213):     at com.testapp.main.BoardFragment.getAddress(BoardFragment.java:6336)
```

Comment: add following permission:access coarse location and access fine location

Comment: These two permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended - So already there.

Comment: I am getting kind of the same problem, which occurs from times to times on certain devices, but with `new Geocoder(context)`. Could you find a reason for that?

Comment: No, the issue is still there. Finding for a solution for a long. Seems related to the change in user location at real time.